# Print message before SIGINT

Tags: c, signals

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* A signal handling function that simply prints
   a message to standard error. */
void handler(int code) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Signal %d caught\n", code);
}

int main() {
    // Declare a struct to be used by the sigaction function:
    struct sigaction newact;

    // Specify that we want the handler function to handle the
    // signal:
    newact.sa_handler = handler;

    // Use default flags:
    newact.sa_flags = 0;

    // Specify that we don't want any signals to be blocked during
    // execution of handler:
    sigemptyset(&newact.sa_mask);

    // Modify the signal table so that handler is called when
    // signal SIGINT is received:
    sigaction(SIGINT, &newact, NULL);

    // Keep the program executing long enough for users to send
    // a signal:
    int i = 0;

    for (;;) {
        if ((i++ % 50000000) == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, ".");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I press ctrl-c, I want my program to print `"Signal %d caught\n"` message then exit normally as it would when pressing ctrl-c.

./test
..............................^CSignal 2 caught
.................^CSignal 2 caught
..........................................^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 ./test

Right now it just prints the message but doesn't exit the program right after.

Comment: If on Linux, read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Since `fprintf`  is not an async-signal-safe function, you are -in principle- not allowed to call it from a signal handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the default behavior of `ctrl+c` is to exit the program. But by using `sigaction()` you are managing the behavior yourself. So if you want the program to end, you can add an `exit()` call.

```
void handler(int code) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Signal %d caught\n", code);
    exit(code);
}
```

Comment: Although a Ctrl-C shouldn't exit as `(1)`.  Ctrl-C is SIGINT, so I'd `return(SIGINT);`  See `signal.h` for all the values.

Comment: Read [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Neither `fprintf` nor `exit` are async-signal-safe, so in principle you should not call them from a signal handler